# How might I successfully solo gank at level 1 with Phantom Assassin?

Tags: dota-2

I'm interested in solo ganking at level 1 with Phantom Assassin, at the very beginning of the match.

Is it possible to do so reliably? What would be the best starting items and ability choice to accomplish this?

Comment: Sure, but there's no surefire method, if that's what you're implying. Hero choice, opponent hero choice, whether you get the jump on them, items, and how you're positioned relative to the creep waves would all have an impact. This is far too broad of a topic to really fit into a single answer.

Comment: Level one gank with PA?  How? Either you have one tiny dagger or you have one blink.  Not much damage, not much chasing power, no evasion, no crit...sure, level 1 ganks can (and do) happen and get kills, but I think PA is probably a poor choice for that.

Comment: Trying to read between the lines here, I'm guessing your intentions are to either a) Play Phantom Assassin effectively, or b) Reliably gank at level 1.  Which one is more important to you?

Comment: The only thing you can solo gank with PA level 1 is a creep.

Comment: PA, despite being a very hard carry, can actually gank pretty effectively if your farm goes well. You definitely need your ultimate though, I probably wouldn't do it before level 7. I would also probably go for BKB. It's something to think about to accelerate your advantage if you find yourself being level 6 or 7 before some of the enemy heroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guaranteed way, but I can imagine scenario with high success rate. You take blink strike and have AA with chilling touch.

If your enemy doesn't have escape skill or isn't very tanky you might succeed. It also helps to have another (preferably ranged stunner) hero with chilling touch buff on him.

Let AA cast chilling touch on you and position yourself so you are between enemy and his retreat zone. Now you can either hit him with normal attacks and then catch up with blink strike or use blink strike first and get the attack speed buff on all hits while enemy is confused.

That's the best I can offer.

Answer (score 10):

You don't. PA doesn't offer much to a gank as a level one hero beyond a 1-second slow and autoattacks.

Answer (score 1):

PA is an end game hero. She does not have many useful active spells compared to other heroes, which is why she is not a good ganker early game.

Nevertheless if you really wanna gank around with her, you can try picking Blink and Dagger up until level 6 and hope you have a nice assisting/stunning/disabling hero with you when you're ganking!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others in PA inability to gank consistently at level 1.
However, if you really insist on doing it,

I suggest you bring 2 supports with you (1 stunner or slower at least),
you should level up phantom strike first as dagger does not provide much at level 1.

Position yourself and the support really well, don't go and hide yourself with the support as this will lead to suspicion of enemy heroes. Instead, lane as natural as possible and ask your support to rotate from behind before executing the lock down spell.

Observe and judge enemy hero before ganking as this will play great roles in determining the results. For example, you might not want to gank level 1 weaver with shukuchi.